# 404 when requesting a single entry in contentful

Tags: http-status-code-404, contentful

I am trying to request a single entry from contentful CMS with the getEntry() method. I keep getting a 404. I really don't understand what am I doing wrong.

```
  export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const p = params.id;
  const client = contentful.createClient({
    space: process.env.CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID,
    environment: process.env.CONTENTFUL_ENVIRONMENT_ID,
    accessToken: process.env.CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN,
  });
  const entry = await client.getEntry(p);
  return { props: { entry: entry } };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a small project to replicate the issue, but I couldn't. It works fine for me. This is what my sample code looks like:

```js
import {createClient} from 'contentful'

export default function Comp() {
    return (
        <div>
            Hello
        </div>
    )
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
    const p = params.id;
    const client = createClient({
      space: process.env.CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID,
      environment: process.env.CONTENTFUL_ENVIRONMENT_ID,
      accessToken: process.env.CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN,
    });
    const entry = await client.getEntry(p);
    return { props: { entry: entry } };
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
    const client = createClient({
        space: process.env.CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID,
        environment: process.env.CONTENTFUL_ENVIRONMENT_ID,
        accessToken: process.env.CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN,
    });
    const entry = await client.getEntries({
        content_type: "blogPost"
    })
    const paths = entry.items.map(item => {return {params: {id: item.sys.id}}});
    return { paths, fallback:true}
}
```

You might be getting a 404 because the paths might be correctly configured. If the above code sample doesn't help, feel free to link the repo or share more details :)